# ¿ Como puedo crear en este código un arrow function?

Tags: javascript, function

estoy intentando hacer arrow function para reducir el código, pero siempre sale error.
¿ Como debo plantear sobre este código ?
Gracias.

```js
const torrente= 'Torrente-4, Lethal Crisis'
const pgTorrente= 13

const nameMiguel= 'Miguel'
const ageMiguel= 43

const nameGuille= 'Guille'
const ageGuille= 11

const entersTorrente =(name, age, isWithAdult)=>{
    if (age >= pgTorrent){
        alert(`${name} puede entrar a ver ${torrente}`)
    } if else=>(sWithAdult){
        alert (`${name} puede pasar a ver ${torrente}.
        Aunque tiene ${age} va con un adulto.`)
    }
    else{
        alert(`${name} no puede entrar a ver ${torrente}.
        Tiene ${age} y necesita tener ${pgTorrente}`)
    }
}

entersTorrente(nameMiguel, ageMiguel)
entersTorrente(nameGuille, ageGuille, true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corregi algunos errores de sintaxis y variables.
1- En vez de if else es `else if` y quite el `=>`
2- En la línea `else if(isWithAdult)` te habías comido la letra `i`.
3- Y las comillas `''` también.
 
Esos son los errores que corregí para que funcione.

```js
const torrente= 'Torrente-4, Lethal Crisis'
const pgTorrente= 13

const nameMiguel= 'Miguel'
const ageMiguel= 43

const nameGuille= 'Guille'
const ageGuille= 11

const entersTorrente =(name, age, isWithAdult)=>{
    if (age >= pgTorrente){
        console.log(`${name} puede entrar a ver ${torrente}`);
    }
  else if(isWithAdult)
    {
        console.log(`${name} puede pasar a ver ${torrente}. Aunque tiene ${age} va con un adulto.`);
    }
    else{
        console.log(`${name} no puede entrar a ver ${torrente}. Tiene ${age} y necesita tener ${pgTorrente}`);
    }
}

entersTorrente(nameMiguel, ageMiguel)
entersTorrente(nameGuille, ageGuille, true)
```

No se si te ayudará, pero funciona al menos.

Comment: Estaría bien que destacaras en la respuesta cuales han sido dichos errores sintácticos para dejárselo más claro al OP.

Comment: disculpa le explico. Mi error , voy a editar la repuesta.

Comment: por cierto cuando tiene en los `console.log` lo siguiente `${torrente}` se refiere a que quiere concatenar el contenido de la variable torrente pero eso es sintaxis php no javascript

Comment: nop , eso es node js, pero como no pude usar node lo use con javascript pero sin salirme tanto de la sintaxis, de lo que quería y hacerlo funcional en el snippet.

Comment: ejecute mi codigo en una pagina online donde ejecutar codigo node js y me funcionó. [Ejecutar Codigo](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_nodejs_online.php)